# ajax response message unique identifier

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['Admin']) {
header('Location: login.php'); exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title> ticketExpress | Admin </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../assets/css/style.css'> 
</head>
<body>
<div id='containerAdmin'>
<h1> <img class='logo' src='../assets/images/logo.png' width='200' height='43'> </h1> <a href='?logout' class='logout'> Logout </a>
<h3> Open Tickets </h3>
<hr />
<?php
require("../configuration/config.php");
$GetTickets = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE open='true'");
while($TicketInfo = $GetTickets->fetch_object()) {
$Subject = $TicketInfo->Subject;
echo "<div id='ticket'>".$Subject ."<a href='?delete=$TicketInfo->ID'><img style='float:right'src='../assets/images/delete.png' width='15px' height='15px'></a><a style='float:right; color:red; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;' href='?close=$TicketInfo->ID'> Close </a><font style='float:right; margin-right:10px;  color:green;' id='responseMsg'> </font></div>";
}
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
$ID = $_GET['delete'];
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','delete.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('responseMsg').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
        }
        ajax.send('delete=$ID');
    </script>
    ";
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
}
if(isset($_GET['close'])) {
$ID = $_GET['close'];
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','close.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('responseMsg').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        } 
        }
        ajax.send('close=$ID');
    </script>
    ";
}
?>
<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that whenever I click delete, the ajax response always appears next to the first ticket on the page (the top one)

If I for example click  "Close" next to ticket 21, the AJAX response "Ticket Succesfully Closed" will always appear next to the first ticket on the page (for example ticket 1)

Here is close.php

```
<?php
require('../configuration/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['close'])) {
echo "Ticket Successfully Closed";
$TID = $_POST['close'];
$con->query("UPDATE tickets SET open='false' WHERE ID='$TID'");
}
```

And delete.php

```
<?php
require('../configuration/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
echo "Ticket Deleted";
$TID = $_POST['delete'];
$con->query("DELETE FROM tickets WHERE ID='$TID'");
}
```

All answers are much appreciated as always! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple DOM elements with same ID. Check your while loop.

Code `document.getElementById('responseMsg')` will always get the first element that exists in DOM.
You are displaying multiple tickets with the same DOM id.

You need to append some unique identifier to element where you want to display server response.

Look at this line:

```
echo "<div id='ticket'>".$Subject ."<a href='?delete=$TicketInfo->ID'><img    style='float:right'src='../assets/images/delete.png' width='15px' height='15px'></a><a style='float:right; color:red; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;' href='?close=$TicketInfo->ID'> Close </a><font style='float:right; margin-right:10px;  color:green;' id='responseMsg'> </font></div>";
```

You could change `id='responseMsg'` to `id='responseMsg{$TicketInfo->ID}'` and then send this ticket ID as a parameter in JavaScript function to target the right one "responseMsg" element.

E.g.

```
echo "<div id='ticket{$TicketInfo->ID}'>". $Subject ."<a href='#' onclick='deleteTicket({$TicketInfo->ID});'><img src="..."></a> <a style='float:right; color:red; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;' href='#' onclick='closeTicket({$TicketInfo->ID});'> Close </a><span style='float:right; margin-right:10px;  color:green;' id='responseMsg{$TicketInfo->ID}'> </span></div>";

<script type='text/javascript'>
function deleteTicket(ticketID) {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open('POST','delete.php', true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('responseMsg'+ticketID).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
  }
  ajax.send('delete='+ticketID);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Im not that savy with JavaScript, can you explain how to create that function?

Comment: I added JS function example and HTML code snippet. Why don't you use some JS library like jQuery? (it would be easier to make ajax requests and modify DOM elements)

Comment: Managed to do it with php, put then in a while loop and attached the ID to each responseMsg